# ASP.NET - Handling different PostBacks

Tags: asp.net, postback

I've got an ASP.NET page on which I've got a GridView which is part of a form. I've enabled editing on the GridView, so it causes a postback to the page.

I've also got a form on the page, which causes a postback when it's submitted.

Can someone tell me how I can distinguish between the two postbacks? When the form is submitted I need to handle that, but not for example when someone hits edit on the GridView.

Thanks.

Comment: It is not recommended to have more than one Form(runat=server) on an ASPX-Page. Why do you need that? You could use one form and handle both events(Button-Click and GridView-RowEditing) in different event-handlers. For further informations see: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-ca/magazine/cc163736.aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you got some code which looks like

```
<asp:Button OnClick="ButtonEventHandler" />
<asp:GridView OnRowEditing="GridViewEditEventHandler" />
```

you could do what ever it was you need to do in the eventhander specific to the event you were interested in handling at that point.

```
  protected void ButtonEventHandler (object sender,  EventArgs e)
  {
    // do stuff from the button click event
  }

  protected void GridViewEditEventHandler(object sender, GridViewEditEventArgs e)
  {
   // do something else from the gridview event
  }
```